# Image Background in React not working as intented

Tags: android, css, image, react-native

I have to make this app on react and to make it interesting i decided to import ImageBackground in my App.js. But when i implemented it nothing happened, the output was still blank. I was confused at first but decided maybe i needed some styling.
What i expected was the image to cover the whole output screen.
However the screen was still blank.
No error messages.

I had a look on the documentation of ImageBackground and used this:

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={require("./assets/myBgImage.png")} style={styles.imgBg}>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);
```

All i get is a blank screen.

But the weird thing is, when i add some text, the part where the text is located is now having
that part with the image. Its hard to explain on text so i will include an image.
Here is the new code:

```
return (
  <View styles={styles.container}>
  <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/myBgImg.png')} styles={styles.imageBg}>
    <Text>1</Text>
    <Text>2</Text>
    <Text>3</Text>
    <Text>4</Text>
    <Text>5</Text>
  </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);
```

And here is the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDkH3.png)

Heres the above mentioned styling:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 24,
  },
  imageBg: {
    flex:1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Here is the background image: [Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRuEX.png)

I've run out of things to do now (which isnt much considering im a beginner at react)
What should i do?

Heres the whole code(I've commented code for later use since the background isnt there):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  ImageBackground,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import djImg from './assets/djImg.png';
import djBgImg from './assets/djBgImg.png';
import useOrientation from './hooks/useOrientation.js' // Portrait and landscape mode

const Width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const Height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const image1 = {
  uri:
    'https://www.fonewalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Border-Edge-Neon-AMOLED-Black-Wallpaper-01-300x585.jpg',
};
/*
function NavigationBar(){

  var orientation = useOrientation();
  var a;

  if(orientation){
    a = 1
  } else if(orientation === false){
    a = 0
  }

  if(a === 1){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text1}>☰       MidiPad</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }  else if(a === 0){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text2}>☰                          MidiPad</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
*/

export default function App() {

  var orientation = useOrientation();
  var a;

  return (
    <View styles={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/djBgImg.png')} styles={styles.imageBg}>
      <Text>1</Text>
      <Text>2</Text>
      <Text>3</Text>
      <Text>4</Text>
      <Text>5</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );

}

/*    if(orientation){
      a = 1
    } else if(orientation === false){
      a = 0
    }

    if(a === 1){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ImageBackground source={image1} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.imageBg}>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      )
    } else if(a === 0){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <NavigationBar />
          <ImageBackground source={image1} style={styles.imageBg}>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      )
    }
*/

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 24,
  },
  text1: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 50,
    color: 'grey',
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  text2: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 220,
    color: 'grey',
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  imgStyle1: {
    transform: [{scale: 0.5}]
  },
  imgStyle2:{
    transform: [{scale: 1.15}],
    marginBottom: 120,
  },
  imageBg: {
    flex:1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#f44336'
  },
});
```

Heres the snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/@atharvasrivastava/midipad

Comment: remove padding,justifyContent and alignItems from styles.container

Comment: still the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blank ImageBackground is not going to help. You need to have some children to get it working. If your wrap your App component code inside `<ImageBackground> Children goes here..</ImageBackground>`  it will work like you see with your contents inside.